# problems getting element position in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATED WITH THE CORRECT FIDDLE LINK

I have the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/kRUym/52/

Every time you click an element of the array it logs to the console its position in the array and the position of the next element. What I'm trying to do is that when I click on the last element I want it to identify that the next element is actually the first (looping the array).

But when when I click on the last element it doesn't set the arrayPos variable (the number of the position in the array: articles) to zero (the first position in the array, it just continues to number 6, even though I have stated in the if argument that if it is bigger than the length of the array it should become zero.

Why is this happening?
Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<div class="item">index 0</div>
<div class="item">index 1</div>
<div class="item">index 2</div>
<div class="item">index 3</div>
<div class="item">index 4</div>
<div class="item">index 5</div>
```

JQUERY

```
var articles = [];
$('.item').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    articles.push(obj);
});

for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    $(articles[i]).data("index", i)
}

$('.item').on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("index");
    console.log('NOW: '+id);
    if(id < articles.length){
        id++
    } else {
        id = 0;
    }
    console.log('NEXT: '+id);
});
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match the code in your question.

Comment: Your code is hopelessly over complex.  `$(".item")` is already an array of items.  Why use a `.each()` look to create another array?  -1 on your question for posting a jsFiddle that was different than the question you actually intended.  I answered based on the jsFiddle because I assumed that's what you were actually working on.

Comment: @jfriend00 You didn't notice the jsFiddle was a mistake because you didn't understand (or read) the question, otherwise you would notice it made no sense. Btw, how can I simplify this array complexity you speak of?

Comment: After making a mistake in your question, you insult me and then ask for my help.  Sorry doesn't work that way.

Comment: @jfriend00 Insult? Where? I just stated that after my mistake you didn't notice it was actually a mistake before answering. Anyway, your comment was very helpful, I have researched on what you said and realised this can definitely be simplified, thanks btw ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's a 1 off issue...try

```
if (id < articles.length - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, you were probably one of the few helpers that noticed that the code I was referring to was the one displayed and not the mistaken fiddle, even though I have updated the question with the correct fiddle, this solves my problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the jQuery `index()`:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    alert( $(this).index() );
});
```

This will alert the index starting from 0.
This requires the items to be in a seperate div, the index is the index relative to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kRUym/51/)**

```
$(function(){

    var articles = [];

    $('article').each(function(){
        articles.push( this );
    });

    $(articles).click(function(){
        console.log( $(this).index() );
    });

});
```

Note that this way you'll just collect the indexable `articles` (every children will always be index 0). You can `push` the JS `this` element into a collection of elements and than on click reference their original index value by wrapping the JS elements into a jQuery Object Elements collection `$(articles)`.